# How to determine the gas price mathematically

Tags: gas, gas-price

The mathematical equation to define the gas price is `gasprice = 1 gwei / gasused`. The mathematical equation to define the tax to be paid for each transaction is `tax = gasprice x gasused`. Are these equations not redundant? If I use 41 000 gas, the gasprice will be approximately `2.43e-5`, if I multiply that value by 41 000 the tax to be paid will be 1 Gwei. Would not that be redundant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gas price is not determined mathematically. It's determined by the people sending transactions. The transaction fee is computed, as you said, by `gasprice x gasused`.

Miner's interest is to earn as much as possible, so they tend to **mine the transactions that have a higher gas price first**.

The interests of the people that send transactions to the network is to have their transactions mined as fast as possible, for the lowest price possible. They can't modify the `gasused`, only the `gasprice`.

So, economically speaking, the more transactions are waiting to be mined, the higher the gas price will be.

You can check [the ethgasstation.info website](https://ethgasstation.info/) to make an impression about what's a decent `gasPrice` at the present moment.

Comment: This price is in Gwei unit, i need to convert it to know the price in Ether, correct?

Comment: yes, the price shown on the ethgasstation is in Gwei.